# Import XXX cannot be resolved for Java SE standard classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse and turns out I have a bunch of import *** not resolved errors.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

All of the above have the same error.
I checked my java version it is 1.7.0 open jdk. I updated Java Home and the JRE library to use. Its still not working.
Note: I imported the code repository from bibucket via the mercurial plugin itself.

Comment: Did you check the installed JREs in your eclipse. Path is windows preferences - > java -> installed JREs

Comment: Your project build path is not configured. You need a JRE entry in there.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - >

Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - >Then select alternate JRE

Comment: Break points? I'm a newbie at Java. 
I usually run the project on the server from eclipse. Now it throws the error.

Comment: @PSR, Why does this answer work? Why wouldn't the default JRE be usable?

Comment: In my case, I selected Default Workspace JRE and it removed the errors.

Answer (score 47):

If the project is Maven, you can try this way :

1. right click the "Maven Dependencies"-->"Build Path"-->"Remove from the build path";
2. right click the project ,navigate to "Maven"--->"Update project....";

Then the import issue should be solved .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was literally pissed off with this import thing.

Comment: I did this for the other maven project that had the class being imported, and it worked

Comment: @Alter.hu it helps me for a while. After i clean my Maven project and change something in my java class(add some code for example) and save - i got the same problem. It repeats all the time. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This helped, along with deleted a specific repo that was giving me problem in my ~/.m2 directory

Comment: Thanks; for me I just need the 2nd step.

Comment: and where can I find "Maven Dependencies"?

Comment: @Line When you import the project is a maven project in eclipse ,it should have a project level's view folder "Maven Dependencies".

Comment: 1+ for giving solution for Maven projects too

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue relating JRE.In my case (eclipse Luna with Maven plugin, JDK 7) I solved this by making ***following change in pom.xml*** and ***then Maven Update Project***.

**from:**

```
 <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

**to:**

```
 <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

---

Screenshot showing problem in JRE:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you have deleted JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY,
then go to your JRE installation and add jars from there.

Eg:-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib   ---add jars from here

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext   ---add jars from here