# Utils cannot be resolved in reading Raw text file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to read text in my raw resource folder

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String fileText = Utils.readRawTextFile(this, R.raw.foodlist);


        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);


        text.setText(fileText);

    }
```

}

I copied a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file)

What is this Utils class, I also looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved)

I already configure its build path to alternate but instead there is no "readRawTextFile" method in the Utils class.

SOLVED :

I found it [here](http://blog.ekledesigns.com/?p=40)

I had to create Utils.java which contain :

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class Utils extends Activity {

    public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
             }
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
         return text.toString();
    }
}
```

thanks everyone!

Comment: do you have a class called Utils?

Comment: @eggblade : please try to read your question as if you did not wrote it. How do you expect someone to know what Utils is supposed to be or where it comes from?

Comment: You have to `import` a class Utils to be able to use it in your code. Shortcut in eclipse: stand on the same line as Utils, then press Ctrl + Shift + 1

Comment: press cntrl + shift + o

Comment: I edited my post, I'm confused about this Utils and couldn't ask in that question because I didn't have enough reputation. That's why I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an import for `Utils` class. Check if it is in your project.
Also, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087674/android-read-text-raw-resource-file) to find working `readRawTextFile` method.

Comment: Yep, actually I copied from that question whereas I don't know what Utils is, I looked up on some question that says I had to configure build path, but that didn't work. In this case what is this Utils?

Comment: My bad, I found that I had to set Utils.java, please look at my first post, it's edited.