# The type java.nio.CharBuffer cannot be resolved

Tags: java, testing, nio

I' am using java jdk1.8.0_05. In the project i get an error as 'The type java.nio.CharBuffer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files' in the line:

`new FileReader(filename).read(buffer);`

How to solve this.

Comment: Check your referenced libraries in project setup -- whenever I get something like this (usually for me it's `java.lang.Object` that can't be resolved) I find that the JRE System Library is mysteriously missing

Comment: I have JRE System Library [jdk1.8.0_05] referenced.

Comment: Could you go into the JRE System Library and verify that the `.class` file is actually there? And/or remove the JRE System Library, save, then add it again?

Comment: I removed the JRE System Library and added it once gain. But, the issue is not solved.

Comment: Did you add it immediately after removing it, or did you close out of the preferences window after removing?

Comment: I tried it both ways. First i removed the JRE library from Java build path and added it immediately. Then, i removed the JRE library  from Java Build path. Closed the properties window and added it again.

Comment: Interesting... What about moving your files to a new project?

Comment: I removed jdk1.8.0_05 and put back jdk1.7.0_55. Now its working. Wasn't able to make it work with jdk1.8.0_05.

Comment: Odd. `CharBuffer` definitely exists in JDK 1.8.0_05... Did you look for the .class file in the library?

Comment: Please post the output of 'java -version'.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is out of date.
The old version that produce the errors is eclipse "Helios". 
I tried the most recent version [Eclipse "Mars"](http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-java-mars-R-win32.zip) and the build passed.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with a recently ported project. My situation was that I installed the newest version of Java on startup and attached it to my previous projects. There was some other minor issues that I fixed but this was not one of them. I found that according to the website, all of the documentation was available, the class was part of my install, however was not found.

I eventually fixed this by just reverting back to JDK1.7. Fixed my problem instantly, but I would love a little more attention and a better answer then changing back versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this with the Hive Web Interface with the war file hive-hwi-0.12.0.war.

General solution:
Locate the new FileReader(filename).read(buffer) statement in the java/jsp code. The method read() with 1 parameter (in this case buffer) is somehow not supported in the "lower" java 1.8 versions. Instead of passing 1 parameter, 3 parameters should be passed: buffer, offset and bufferlength. Change the statement in "new FileReader(filename).read(buffer,0,buffer.length);"

For Hive Web Interface in file view_file.jsp change statement "cread=br.read(c)" into "cread=br.read(c,0,c.length)".

Comment: Very hard to believe, impossible actually, and doesn't have anything to do with `CharBuffer.`

Answer (score 0):

I realize this comes a bit late, but it's not marked as solved, so I'll share.

I had this experience with `java.nio.FloatBuffer` in a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04, using OpenJDK 8. You didn't specify which OS you're using, so here's what fixed it for me:

Install the `openjdk-7-jre-lib` package; e.g. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-lib`

Note that there's no `openjdk-8-jre-lib` package in the default list of repositories.

This assumes you have your build path properly configured. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved) SO post for more info on that.

Answer (score -1):

I am using eclipse mars first we need to check the Jre installed libraries and build them,after that clean u r project now the problem is resolved.

Comment: It is great experince because I am new for these window based Application@Adhi