# java.util.arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I had a spring project that was working fine.
I updated the java platform i had on my machine ( through out the java update notif that comes auto )

after that update I had a blue screen while i was coding and now i can't deploy the solution on Tomcat since i keep having this error :

```
Aug 21, 2014 5:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'arepScreeningController' defined in file [E:\ORQR\css\code\IDE\webapps\AfDB-CSS\WEB-INF\classes\com\gcap\css\controller\ArepScreeningController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.gcap.css.controller.ArepScreeningController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.gcap.css.controller.ArepScreeningController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved
    Arrays cannot be resolved

    at com.gcap.css.controller.ArepScreeningController.<init>(ArepScreeningController.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 22 more
```

and when i checked the controller i found that :
`import java.util.Arrays;` cannot be resolved now im my project!

a little help to solve this issue will be much appreciated!

thank you!

Comment: how do you compile your project ?

Comment: @fadwa which version of java and what type of application

Comment: See if this can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a long shot but since you got a blue screen just before this happened it could be that the Java installation is corrupted. Create a new basic project and try to use `Arrays` from it, if the problem persist, re-install Java; if not you have some configuration issue, it might come from Maven or similar if you are using those.