# JSP The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, classpath

This is my code for test.jsp, I can't resolve the error by importing java.util.Arrays. Why? I want to change my array to string instead of [Ljava.lang.String;@71810ee1 which I got from out.println(a);.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<% String[] a = request.getParameterValues("multiple");
if(a!=null)
{
    String res = Arrays.toString(a);
    out.println(res);
    //out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
//out.println(Integer.parseInt(a[i])); //If integer
%></br><%
out.println(a[i]);
}}
%>
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.jsp" method="get">
<select name="multiple" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 7 in the generated java file
The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
Arrays cannot be resolved


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

My current result is 
1 2 3
My desired result is 
[1, 2, 3] 
which can be stored in a string.

Comment: have you tried to combine the import statement? `<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.Arrays" %>`

Comment: @Baby yes, the result is the same.

Comment: make sure you import the library in your project's  java Build Path under `JRE System Libary` called `jfxrt.jar`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I've import the library in my project's build path.

Comment: @BeginningMyJava I know you did but kindly check if the `jfxrt.jar` is located there.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes jfxrt.jar is located there

Comment: @BeginningMyJava how about `rt.jar`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin My library have "resources.jar,rt.jar,jsse.jar,jce.jar,charsets.jar,jfr.jar,access-bridge-64.jar,cldrdata.jar,dnsns.jar,jaccess.jar,jfxrt.jar,localedata.jar,nashorn.jar,sunec.jar,sunjce_provider.jar,sunmscapi.jar,sunpkcs11.jar,zipfs.jar". Yes it does have rt.jar.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin That class was added to Java 1.2 in about 1998. It has nothing whatsoever to do with JavaFX.

Comment: Please check the following link it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: @AshokNanda tried all of them but none worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.
For those who want to do the same as me.

```
if(a!=null)
{

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
//out.println(Integer.parseInt(a[i])); //If integer
//out.println(a[i]);
value += a[i]+" ";

}
out.println(value);
}
```

without the need to import array :)