# not able to import a class from a generated jar file

Tags: java, jar, wsdl

I have created a jar file from a set of java classes and added the jar to my buildpath in eclipse. Now when I try to import a class from the jar in my code, it is showing "The import cannot be resolved"

I used the following command to generate the .class files

**wsimport -keep -B-XautoNameResolution -p addressServices.wsdl .wsdl**

Then generated a jar file with the following command

**jar -cvf addressservices.jar -p addressservices.wsdl  ./addressservices/wsdl/*.class**

Now when I try to import the class files from above jar file, getting error "The import addressServices cannot be resolved"

**import addressServices.wsdl.AddressStandardizationResponseGlobalZ;**

**public interface AddressService {
    AddressStandardizationResponseGlobalZ getStandardizedAddress();**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved/16919015#16919015

Comment: show us some code, please. Which is the class you're trying to import? How is the dependency to this jar added? Where do you import the class?

Comment: Hi Alexander I have added few more details hope this can help you