# Eclipse showing red cross for valid java statements

Tags: java, eclipse

I've forked and imported project from Github using Eclipse. But I am getting red cross at a lot of places which is valid java code. Also the keyword highlighting features etc have gone as a part of this.

I've ran the application in tomcat (from within eclipse) and it seems to work fine. How can I avoid this? What am I doing wrong?

[image: Red cross]

Edit: I am able to solve the red cross issue, answer posted below. But I still can't get the syntax highlighting for Java code to work in the JSP. I've tried solutions posted in stackoverflow like opening it with the JSP Editor, which I am doing. The project is already a webproject. What more can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does the error state?

Comment: The one at line 3 says, `import java.sql cannot be resolved`

Comment: Use code, not screenshots. This is StackOverflow, not flickr ;)

Comment: @phaberest Haha +1 for the Flickr comment

Comment: @phaberest I used the screenshot because I wanted to show that the problem was with eclipse and not the code.

Comment: Images are not indexed, that makes your question unsearchable from others who may have the same problem. Help others find a solution that others already encountered is part of our community scope

Comment: @phaberest Doesn't the text in the question and the heading do that job? I wasn't even sure that stackoverflow was the right place to post the question

Comment: Have you ever searched for a solution on Google? You always write down the error/exception or a piece of your failing code. None of them in this question. SO is surely the right place, yep. Welcome, anyway! ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very silly error but since I've figured it out, I'll post the answer for others who might encounter the same. The github project I cloned had using a different version of java(1.6). So I went and changed it the version in my system 1.8, and the errors have gone.

Edit: Although the errors are gone, the syntax highlighting for the java code within the jsp is still absent.