# java.util.Scanner cannot be resolved

Tags: java

This is my current code which is inside a `javatogo` package and a class file named `Console.java`.

```
package javatogo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {

    /**
     * Private static Scanner for multiple use.
     */
    
    // update: I did have System.in - I just did not copy and paste
    // the code directly from my project since it has things not needed
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    /**
     * Static method to return a user input.
     * 
     * @param line
     * @return String
     */
    
    public static String readLine(
            String line
    ) {
        System.out.print(line);
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

}
```

I found the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read a console input which uses the `java.util` package and the `Scanner.java` however when I hit `CTRL+SHIFT+O` to automatically import or manually import it, I get an error on the import and instance:

> Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
>
> The import java.util.Scanner cannot be resolved

Any help would be appreciated, I have refreshed Eclipse and restarted it - I am still receiving this error.

Note: When I change the import to `import java.util.*` I receive no further errors on the import but the `Scanner` instance still errors.

Update: I took a [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDSAp.jpg) if it helps anyone.

Resolved because I updated my Java, I had to manually tell Eclipse my JDK path.

Thanks to [@Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) for the answer and everyone who helped.

Comment: I don't know Eclipse, but others IDE can't find system classes when the project JDK is not defined. Try deleting the project and maybe event reinstalling Eclipse

Comment: What if you use the fully qualified name? `java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner()`

Comment: I still receive the error, I took a [print screen](http://imgur.com/a/QXPSi) if it helps anyone understand. @JornVernee

Comment: Gonna guess that your project setup isn't right. You probably need to tell it where your Java installation lives.

Comment: Strange because it was only this morning I was working on a different project using the `Scanner` and it worked fine, I just loaded it and now it is erroring also. I will follow your advise and re install the Eclipse if deleting the project and making another doesn't work @Raffaele

Comment: Try Project -> Clean... -> Clean all projects. It may also help to start Eclipse in clean mode as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: Error suggests that your project can't find location of proper JRE/JDK. If it worked earlier then change current JDK/JRE used in your project to alternative one which worked in different projects. Take a look here to see how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919015/1393766

Comment: That fixed the issue, if you change this to an answer I will accept it - thank-you so much! Maybe its because I updated my Java not long ago (I should of probably stated that but it didn't play on my mind - apologies) @Pshemo

Comment: java.util.Scanner was first added to jdk in 1.5. So if you are using a java version older than that, you might get that error.