# Eclipse error: “The import ... cannot be resolved”

Tags: java, eclipse

I know I am asking the very popular question. But I can not find the solution to the problem. I have a sandbox to which I added a code of the unit test `MulticurveBuildingDiscountingDiscountAUDTest.java` file and commented it.

Then I added the main method and I could successfully run the program (print something in a console).

Finally, I uncommented the code of the `MulticurveBuildingDiscountingDiscountAUDTest.java` file and I saw the following error:

```
The import com.opengamma.analytics.financial.instrument.index.GeneratorSwapFixedONMaster cannot be resolved.
```

And further in the code:

```
GeneratorSwapFixedONMaster cannot be resolved
```

I know that this import is located in the `og-analytics src/test/java` location, which I believe is not listed anywhere in the build path. I believe the problem is with a build path options and specially with classes like GeneratorSwapFixedONMaster which were created specially for tests. I have been playing around with cleaning, rebuilding projects, reinstalling and as a result updating the JRE. I have visited these [Import *** cannot be resolved [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved?noredirect=1&lq=1) and these [Eclipse error: “The import XXX cannot be resolved”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893/eclipse-error-the-import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved) questions.
Do you know what shall I do to cure the following error?

I have many problems with other imports from the original `MulticurveBuildingDiscountingDiscountAUDTest.java` file as well.

**Update**: #1 is a location of my file. #2 is the location of classes this project uses. The `MulticurveBuildingDiscountingDiscountAUDTest.java` file is taken from the `src/test/java`

[image: screenshot]

**Update 2**: one may see that in Libraries I have included all the dependencies I might need (at least I do not know what else to add). The Maven Dependencies contains the hole `og-analytics` package:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Is it a Maven project? Could you give an example: in which class the import cannot be resolved and where is this class located (in `src/main/java` of the project `og-analytics`)? Where is the missing class (in `src/test/java` of the same project, in a different project, in a JAR or Maven dependency, ...)?

Comment: Dear @howlger, I have included update. All projects are using Maven.

Comment: Why is your MulticurveBuildingDiscountingDiscountAUDTest unit test located in the `src/main/java`? Tests should be in `src/test/java`. Also you will not going to see files in `src/test/java` in other modules it will be run during the build, but the class files will not be in the final jar, therefore you cannot refer classes in src/main from src/test (you can do the other way around only).

Comment: To solve given issue Please follow below link [stackoverflow.com/a/48381463/5093657](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48381463/5093657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included the **source (`src`) folder** `og-analytics/src/main/java` which contains the `*.java` files **instead of the classes (`bin` or `classes`) folder** with the `*.class` files (in your case, probably `og-analytics/target/classes`).

But instead using *Add Class Folder...* you should add the project `og-analytics` in the tab *Projects*. Or even better, in the Maven `pom.xml` file add the dependency to the project `og-analytics` like you did for `og-util`.

Comment: I was playing with howlger and @GhostCat suggestions and other ideas I found in the internet. I do not know what has happened. I made too much changes, I believe that updating Maven finally solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this import is located in the og-analytics src/test/java location, which I believe is not listed anywhere in the build path.

Perfectly explains your problem. In order to import any class, you must either have the source in your build path, or some directory that contains a compiled version of that class. It is that simply.

The answer is: get clear on your project setup. If you intend to use classes from somewhere, you have to make them available somehow. Otherwise it will not work. In your case: if your *tests* want to make use a certain thing - then you should probably add that "thing" to your *test* project (you should avoid putting test-only stuff to your "product" projects).

That is all there is to this.

Comment: dear @GhostCat, I have updated the question. From the second screenshot you may see that I am using all needed libraries: explicitly stated og-analytics/src/test, in Maven Dependencies I have og-analytics and rest of jar-s.