# "The import org cannot be resolved" error with the imports in Eclipse Photon with selenium Standalone server 3.9.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, import, webdriver

I'm creating a basic selenium Webdriver program by adding the selenium jars and relative jars, below is my code. but when i try to resolve firefordriver and webdriver for importing them. im getting "The import org cannot be resolved" error.

Environment details:

> JavaSe-10.
>
> Eclipse Version  Photon Release (4.8.0) Build id: 20180619-1200
>
> Selenium StandAlone server 3.9.1

Code:

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverBasics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //1. Firefox browser. 
        //geckodriver.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","d:\\installations\\eclipse\\jars\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: hard to say. do you have the latest versions of the needed jars? [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) and [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

delete module-info.java file or any other module file that was created at the time of creating the project. That will resolve the issue.

[image: module-info.java]

[image: error resolved]

Comment: Can you kindly explain why is that?

Comment: @Line module-info.java need to be in the appropriate sub-directory. The .java files don't need to be on the classpath, but on the source path. (The generated .class files need to be on the classpath.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the jar files responsible for spring framework were not their in the JRE, so i downloaded the respective jars and added in the build path.

below is the link which i followed and it worked for me.

Remember to see the section : "2) Add spring jar files" from the below link:

[refer this link](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-spring-application-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Add **selenium jars** and other required jars to **build path of your project** in Eclipse and **Rebuild the project**.

Answer (score 0):

Add jars like this

> Right click on project  --> Configure BuildPath --> Java Build Path
>   Libraries -->
>
> Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY --> Then select alternate JRE

From C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib your path where you store JRE

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved-for-java-se-standard-classes)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
The import org cannot be resolved
```

...implies that your program was unable to resolve the following **imports**:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

Your main issue for the **imports** not getting reslved is **circular-dependency**.

Though you have added all the **selenium jars** and **relative jars** but you have named the program *Module* / *Package* as **selenium** as follows:

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

This is causing a **circular-dependency** hence the imports are not getting resolved through the *selenium* related jars.

### Solution

Changing/Modifying the *Module* / *Package* name from `selenium` to something else, e.g. **`myProgram`** will solve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove the module-info.java class from project it will works.
Module info is not required for selenium project. So you can remove it :)