# Java 11 without modularity: package does not exist while it is added as maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, java-11

I have three very simple applilcations. One is COMMON which I will center security configs, other with ZUUL feature and the third is a EUREKA SERVER. Both are Spring Boot and Java 11. Although I am using Java 11 I am not reling on modularity (as far as I know it will not make sense use modularity feature with Spring Boot).

When I run all three in Eclipse I successfully can run the server, common and zuul in that sequence. When I try to maven build I get the error mentioned in subject.

The immediate explanation would be "you don't have common in zuul classpath". Well, as far as I check I do have common in zuul classpath. I am wondering if there is any extra config because I am using Java 11 but not using modularaty.

By saying I am using Java 11 but not modularity I mean, I have Java 11 but I don't have module-info.java at all in any of the three projects.

Checking in .m2 folder and unzip the common.jar I do see the class complained.

Zuul project pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zuul</name>
    <description>Zuul project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Evidence that common is the maven dependences

[image]

Error during mvn clean install:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< com.test:zuul >----------------------------
[INFO] Building zuul 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ zuul ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ zuul ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\_d\WSs\soteste\zuul\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[14,32] package com.test.common.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JwtConfig
  location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[46,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JwtConfig
  location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[47,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JwtConfig
  location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.778 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-21T14:23:23-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project zuul: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[14,32] package com.test.common.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JwtConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[46,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JwtConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[47,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JwtConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The class complained is in the jar

[image]

*** Edited

Common pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>Zuul project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the common's project pom.xml?

Comment: Eugen Covaci, I added common pom

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: What happens if you close the common-project in Eclipse?

Comment: If you run **mvn clean install** for the common project it should work

Comment: I just made a test, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the *common* project is a Spring Boot Application (I see the BOOT-INF folder inside the generated jar).

From [Use a Spring Boot Application as a Dependency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html) documentation:

> The executable archive **cannot be used as a dependency** as the
>   executable jar format packages application classes in BOOT-INF/classes.
>   This means that they cannot be found when the executable jar is used
>   as a dependency.
>
> To produce the two artifacts, one that can be used as a dependency and
>   one that is executable, a classifier must be specified. This
>   classifier is applied to the name of the executable archive, leaving
>   the default archive for use as a dependency.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is an example:

[image]

The first jar is build as dependency-able, the second one is Spring Boot executable.

Comment: Eugen Covaci, I added the plugin above (classifier) to zuul and I am still getting the same error. In fact, no change at all when mvn clean compile

Comment: @JimC You have to run: **mvn clean install** to have it in the maven local repository

Comment: Eugen Covaci, same error. ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project zuul: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[14,32] package com.test.common.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/_d/WSs/soteste/zuul/src/main/java/com/test/zuul/security/SecurityTokenConfig.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JwtConfig
[ERROR]   location: class com.test.zuul.security.SecurityTokenConfig

Comment: @JimC Did you run: **mvn clean install** on the common project? In the target directory you should see 2 jars, one with `exec` inside the name

Comment: Yes, I ran mvn clean install firstly in common succesfully and then unsuccesfuly in zuul. In common target folder I have only common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. I added the classifier only in ZUUL project. Should I added in it in COMMON instead?

Comment: @JimC You should add it only in the common project

Answer (score 1):

That Eclipse is able to resolve Eclipse projects of the currently open workspace as Maven dependencies into other projects is a specialty of Eclipse.

If you execute Maven on command-line or from within Eclipse you leave the sphere of Eclipse and use plain Maven. Plain Maven (even the in Eclipse integrated Maven) does not know about Eclipse projects, it only knows the artifacts available in your local and the configured remote repositories.

Therefore the correct approach in your case is to first execute `mvn install` on your **common** project. This installs common into your local repo and makes it available to Maven.

Afterwards you can execute `mvn clean install` on your **zuul** project.

Comment: Robert, the correct aproach you mentioned is exactly what I am doing via PowerShell