# Cannot resolve the coldfusion import in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, coldfusion, import

Im trying to invoke a ColdFusion component from java by using the CFCProxy Object, however when I try to do the import:

```
import coldfusion.cfc.CFCProxy;
```

I get the error message:

```
The import coldfusion cannot be resolved.
```

Can anyone tell me what this means and give some direction on how to fix the issue?

Comment: See this related question: [Eclipse error: “The import XXX cannot be resolved”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4322893/1636917)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .jar containing this class is in the Java Build Path of your project.
To find out which jars are in your build path, go to 
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->Libraries.

As far as I know Coldfusion is proprietary software, so you should contact them to find out where you can get the necessary jars.

Comment: Can you be more specific? 
How would I check the build path?
And if the .jar file is missing, where can I find it?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve the problem with your help. 
For anyone interested, the jar files needed are found in the path:
c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\lib\cfusion.jar;
c:\coldfusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib\cfmx_bootstrap.jar

Comment: user3033588 - You might want to post that last comment as an "answer" so it is more visible. You can do that and still mark @jny's response as the answer.