# The import javax.net cannot be resolved within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl

I try to import an Eclipse projet which works fine on another computer, and i get this error on Eclipse :

**The import javax.net cannot be resolved**

```
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
```

How can i solve this ? Is there a missing package to install ?

Comment: I guess your jdk is < JDK7 as this class is added in JDK7

Comment: X509TrustManager is since 1.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse error: "The import XXX cannot be resolved"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893/eclipse-error-the-import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Double check that it's actually on the Java Build Path. And by that I mean look in every jar there to make sure you see it.