# Import cannot be resolved in java

Tags: java, package

[image]I am getting:

```
import com.test.foo.A cannot be resolved
```

IDE I am using is NWDS.

I have a class A which is declared as public, I have a class B which is declared as public final. Both are declared in different packages.

Class A in com.test.foo

Class B in com.test.foo1

I am trying to import a public method from class A to class B but I am getting the above mentioned error in IDE.

Both are in different projects.

Code snippet as below :-

```
package com.test.foo 

public class A {

    public static void method1(){
    ....some code ....
    }

}

-----

package com.test.foo1

import com.test.foo.A // i'm getting error here as import cannot be resolved

public final class B {

    private method2(){

    ...... some code....
     A.method1(); // import cannot be resolved error
    }
}
```

Can any help help on this?

Thanks in advance for you help :)

Comment: Please include the code where you are having the `import` failure.

Comment: Are they in same project? Of if different ones, is the dependency configured well?

Comment: @PavanKumar in different projects and dependency has been configured.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen code snippet added :)

Comment: What is the directory structure of `A.java` and `B.java` ?  Does it follow the package names exactly?

Comment: @NeethuShaji may be you can share the screenshot that depicts the folder structure. can you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :
Yes they follow the same package strtucture
that is Class A is present in package com.test.foo of Project1
and Class B is present in package com.test.foo1 of Project2

I hope i am making myself clear :)
Let me know

Comment: @PavanKumar : I am sorry i cannot share the exact code screenshot here.
I can provide you with the details though :)

Comment: @NeethuShaji No, they have to share the same folder structure, meaning _both_ projects are in `test/com`

Comment: @PavanKumar : attached the screenshot :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :please see the screenshot :)

Comment: To solve given issue Please follow below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381463/5093657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your image you have the class **ClassA not A**.

So the error is:

```
 "import com.test.foo.A cannot be resolved"
```

You should import the class `ClassA`.

```
package com.test.foo1

import com.test.foo.ClassA;

public final class B {

  private method2(){

    //...... some code....
    ClassA.method1(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help :)
that was a mistake from my end :(

the screenshot i shared was just an example but for the actual code its still "Import cannot be resolved"

in this case the solution is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

This is like trying to copy text by clicking "copy" button on a computer, and clicking "paste" button on another computer. Quite amusing. :-)

- Well, a general Java way is you build the project that contains A as a JAR, and use it as a library in another project that contains B.
- Or if you organize your project using Maven, you can import another project as dependency. Something like:

?

```
<project>
   ...
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>yourgroup</groupId>
         <artifactId>myejbproject</artifactId>
         <version>2.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>path/to/myejbproject.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: @kevin Wang

thanks for your reply
but this won't work

we are not using MAVEN build. And i have already made the dependency clear :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, uh? would you elaborate why not? the problem he is facing is that class A is not in class path, so can be resolved.

Comment: I have the feeling that he is dealing with code that he wrote himself, and not external JARs, which therefore means code which won't be managed by Maven.

Comment: @NeethuShaji, sorry I don't know about the IDE you're using, bottom line is you could go with the JAR way, which isn't ideal if you need to modify the classes in both projects. Maybe someone know the IDE also know a trick to get it work. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWang i have attached the screenshot 
could you please have a look and let me know :)

Comment: @NeethuShaji from the screenshot you posted it, yeah, it is ClassA, not just A. BTW, your IDE seems to me just good old Eclipse, is it called NWDS now?

Comment: @KevinWang 
Since i cannot post the screenshot of the actual code here. I tried wrote the same in Eclipse and pasted the screenshot. 
Also, yes that was a typo from my end about ClassA Sorry for that :(

The actual code is written in NWDS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To solve given issue Please follow below link [stackoverflow.com/a/48381463/5093657](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48381463/5093657)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you imported the right class and still getting this error, use this trick.

**`Remove the import statement and re-import it.`**