# how to build 6.3-SNAPSHOT from the source in Github if I want to use new ChartJs

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 6.2. I wanted to use ChartJS. 
The problem is that I am not an Elite subscriber and I find the solution in this post:
[primefaces-chartjs-can-not-be-resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322827/primefaces-chartjs-can-not-be-resolved)

my question s how can I build 6.3-SNAPSHOT from the source in Github with eclipse. I have a maven project in eclipse witch I want to test the new ChartJS.

Comment: Did you try posting 'build primefaces from source'  in a searchengine? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Building-From-Source

Comment: Thank you for the link. I followed the tutorial and managed to create the primefaces-6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar. now I do not know how to integrate it into the pom.xml. I add the jar in the java build path and it works for thr import but when i run the project I get this : <p:lineChart> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: lineChart

Comment: Did you try a searchengine for the generic 'issue' behind this error? _"Tag Library supports namespace: primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: ..."_

Comment: Check for the presence more than one (older) version

Comment: yes I still have the primefaces 6.2 dependency in the pom.xml. if i delete it i get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.encoder.Encode.

Comment: Two versions in the same application is not (never) supported. Fix that part and create a new question or something similar (or an issue in the PrimeFaces github if you think it is a regression in PrimeFaces) (or do you use it yourself?)

Comment: I resolve it by adding Maven Repository: org.owasp.encoder  to the pom.xml and its work now ! thanks for the support !