# chromedriver cannot be resolved error shows in selenium JAVA on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to do some automation projects with chrome, java and selenium and having problems importing the chrome driver.

Error: import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.chromedriver cannot be resolved

Can anyone help me for this ?

Comment: make sure your library import is correct, `import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; ` Show us your code if thats not the case

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project by navigating to the following menu item:

`Project > Clean...` then click on `Project > Build Automatically`
If that doesn't work, try removing the jars from the build path and adding them again.

please take a look at the code here - https://gist.github.com/ajinkya-mundankar/3768339eeb54755d937386138582dca0

you can refer from here - [Eclipse error: "The import XXX cannot be resolved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893/eclipse-error-the-import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Selenium 3.x you have to mention the **`Key-Value`** pair using
`System.setProperty()` line mandatory as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Sample code is like this

public class SitePoster {

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./pathtodriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("//https://google.co.in")
```