# The import java.util.stream.Collectors cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, collectors

My Maven project in Eclipse was running just fine this week all the way up until just now, when it started giving me this error, and I have no idea what's up because my build path is correct for JDK 16. All the posts I've seen about this error are about JDK7/8 path issues from years ago. Am I missing something here?
[image][image]

edit: This is what it shows under the JRE System Library in the Configure Build Path window. In the Package Explorer under JRE System Library it does show the java.base JAR with the java.util.stream package as expected.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you expand the JRE System Library, what do you see?

Comment: I see a bunch of packages listed, nothing out of the ordinary. Should I be looking for something specific? I don't remember modifying the build path recently.

Comment: Did you try the option `Project -> Clean`, and other various one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4322893/5668956) ?

Comment: It's difficult to help when you don't show us what you see.

Comment: I did clean the project and re-added the library to the build path multiple times with no change to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to delete the project in Eclipse and then import it. Seems like a known Eclipse glitch that doesn't have a better known solution yet.